# How to Use a Table Prefix in Doctrine2's NamingStrategy Interface?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I want to duplicate our existing table structure, and we use table prefixes for all columns:

```
table name: 
  TBLO_TABLE_ONE
table columns:
  TBLO_COLUMN_ONE
  TBLO_COLUMN_TWO
  etc...
```

However, the Doctrine Interface for NamingStrategy does not seem to accommodate. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've submitted a pull request to Doctrine2 github repository, adding this functionality.

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/357